# Use Exchange Web Services to enumerate all the properties(mapi properties?) on a mail item

Tags: mapi, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to troublshoot a problem with some mail items in on an Exchange 2007 server.  I've been able to determine there is something wrong with I think a reciepient property, but I'm not sure, so I'd like to just enumerate all the properties on a message on a bad one and compare it to a good one.

I would also settle for a MAPI or WebDAV solution.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you found a solution to your problem, I'll still answer your original question.

No, there is not a way to enumerate *all* of the properties on a message in EWS.  It you can only return the properties provided by the AllProperties flag (which doesn't return custom & named properties), or specific properties you provide by using the ExtendedProperty syntax.

[Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/bec6e124-31bd-47e1-a81e-f7c18cc48470/) is a brief example of adding a custom extended property.

And so you know, MFCMAPI is still actively developed and hosted at CodePlex ([MFCMAPI at CodePlex)](http://www.codeplex.com/MFCMAPI)

Answer (score 0):

I found a utility on Microsoft's site that allows you to browse a MAPI store, so this worked better for my purposes than writing some code could have.  Neat little utility to point at an MS Exchange store.

[MFCMapi from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=55FDFFD7-1878-4637-9808-1E21ABB3AE37&displaylang=en)